# Symfony2 Routing with Folders (containing multiple forward slashes)

Tags: symfony

I am looking to setup some routes in Symfony2, but I am struggling to setup a dynamic route for folders.

I am trying to setup a route that accepts the following: /department/sub-department/sub-sub-department/product-url.html

From that route all I need is the product-url and the rest is more for SEO. The problem I have is that a route may have many department levels in the URL, so I need to ignore everything before the product-url.

It seems like the "/" is the problem here, so is there a way to escape the slashes.

If I don't use any of the departments in the routing I can use this:

```
product:
    pattern:  /{url}.html
    defaults: { _controller: CompanyBundle:System:pageRequest }
```

So, I basically need something like this:

```
product:
    pattern:  /{department}/{url}.html
    defaults: { _controller: CompanyBundle:System:pageRequest }
```

Where the {department} can be one or more departments with forward slashes in.

Is that possible at all?

Comment: The pattern is interpreted as an regular expression, so you can write it just as as an regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a nice article about it in the [cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/slash_in_parameter.html):

> You must explicitly allow / to be part of your parameter by specifying a more permissive regex pattern.

In your case the route definition would have to be

```
product:
    pattern: /{department}/{url}.html
    defaults: { _controller: CompanyBundle:System:pageRequest }
    requirements:
        department: ".+"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
product:
    pattern: /{url}.html
    defaults: { _controller: CompanyBundle:System:pageRequest, department: ~ }

product_department:
    pattern: /{department}/{url}.html
    defaults: { _controller: CompanyBundle:System:pageRequest }
    requirements:
        department: '[\w\d\/\-]+'
```